# preview GUI in NetBeans while using code to build GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

How do you view a `JFrame` GUI design if you build your frame in code from a constructor?

(There is no design preview if you create object or extend from JFrame?)

I want to create a GUI by writing Java code so that I can learn more about Java GUI concepts, but it is annoying to have to run app every 5 sec to see how my buttons fit.

Comment: I don't think you can, you have to use the "JFrame form" option to see  the preview of the frame

Answer (score 1):

Previewing a Swing GUI in NetBeans requires the auto-generated *.form (xml) file which corresponds to the code. If you write the code by hand, you will not have the necessary xml metadata to preview it.